# Permutation with repetition.

Tags: combinatorics

My question is :

Consider the word "Question three"

Accounting for order, find number of ways four letters can be selected from the thirteen.

Allow the letters to be selected multiple times regardless of how many times it occurs in the original list of letters.For example when selecting three letters from "this" ,the selection "SSS"or "HHI" could be made

Since order is required so this is a permutation problem.My point of view is since  there are $10$ distinct letters,and $4$ letters are to be selected with repitition allowed so answer should be $10^4$I think this will include all possible cases.

I think I am correct but I did not find such type of problem anywhere so for confirmation that i am correct or not I need your help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I agree with your reasoning exactly.  There are 10 different letters and you deem order to be important.  If there was only 1 letter to be selected, you would have $10$ possibilities.  With two letters, $10 \times 10$ possibilities.  And so forth.

Comment: Yes, I also agree. If you go with a case-by-case analysis (i.e. if the four letters are different; if two letters are the same and the other two are different; if three letters are the same and one letter is different; if all four letters are the same; if two letters are the same and the other two letters are the same) then you will also get $10^4$ possibilities.

Comment: Usually, in these types of questions, a letter is only permitted to be used as often as it appears in the word or phrase.  In this case, that means you would only be allowed to use the letters q, u, s, i, o, n, h, and r once, the letter t twice, and the letter e three times.  You would then consider cases based on the number of times a letter is repeated.  That said, if the sentence "Allow the letters to be selected multiple times regardless of how many times it occurs in the original list of letters." is part of the original question, you have solved it correctly.